# Efficient ROW_NUMBER increment when column matches value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find an efficient way to derive the column `Expected` below from only `Id` and `State`. What I want is for the number `Expected` to increase each time `State` is `0` (ordered by `Id`).

```
+----+-------+----------+
| Id | State | Expected |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 |     0 |        1 |
|  2 |     1 |        1 |
|  3 |     0 |        2 |
|  4 |     1 |        2 |
|  5 |     4 |        2 |
|  6 |     2 |        2 |
|  7 |     3 |        2 |
|  8 |     0 |        3 |
|  9 |     5 |        3 |
| 10 |     3 |        3 |
| 11 |     1 |        3 |
+----+-------+----------+
```

I have managed to accomplish this with the following SQL, but the execution time is very poor when the data set is large:

```
WITH Groups AS 
(
   SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS GroupId FROM tblState WHERE State=0
)
SELECT S.Id, S.[State], S.Expected, G.GroupId FROM tblState S
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 GroupId FROM Groups WHERE Groups.Id <= S.Id ORDER BY Id DESC) G
```

Is there a simpler and more efficient way to produce this result? (In SQL Server 2012 or later)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a cumulative sum:

```
select s.*,
       sum(case when state = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as expected
from tblState s;
```

Comment: Omg, that was ridiculously simple. Thank you, works like a charm it seems! :)

Answer (score 0):

Other method uses `subquery` :

```
select *,
       (select count(*)
        from table t1
        where t1.id < t.id and state = 0
       ) as expected
from table t;
```